# Individual User 'top 5' lists

Tags: drupal, sorting, drupal-6, drupal-views, flags

I am aiming to produce a individual top 5 list for each user of my drupal site. now trying to work this one out has become quite difficult and hence why i am here.

what im looking for is a top 5 list which allows the user to select nodes to be ranked by the user.

so at anytime the user can edit the list and re-order the list.

I am aware that this may require me creating my own module, however i believe there must be somebody who has done it before or have any information to set me along the right tracks.

I am currently using views and flags to hold a number of 'favourite nodes' list which works brilliantly. however, being able to organise a top 5 list, is where I come up slightly short.

any info much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to create a top 5 list as selected by the individual user, using flags to select my favourite items, draggableviews to order my favourites and views itself to create the top 5 list.

then by adding a display I made the page display allow the user to edit their list and then have the block display to display it for the user.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a job for...Nodequeue!  http://drupal.org/project/nodequeue

Try it along with Smartqueue per user: http://drupal.org/project/smartqueue_users

Comment: Problem comes with that module that each user needs to create their own list, before adding to it. plus the countless bugs..

Comment: First I should state that I haven't used Smartqueue Per User so I can't speak to the bugs, but the project page claims the queues are created for the users automatically.